# Multiple tables join and applying case when

Tags: sql, oracle, tibero

I am trying to use case when phrase to change the result value while joining multiple tables.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CENSUS = '0' THEN 'SP_CENSUS0' END AS SP_RESULT FROM SP
SELECT CASE WHEN CENSUS = '0' THEN 'SR_CENSUS0' END AS SR_RESULT FROM SR

    SP             SR          TARGET
   ------         ------      --------
   CODE           CODE        CODE
   CENSUS         CENSUS
```

and I wish to join the  three tables TARGET, SP and SR while
SP AND SR should do 1:1 mapping and hope to use column CODE to be used 
for join. Each CENSUS colulmn may/may not have different results.

I want something like this to be in my result

```
      SP_RESULT            SR_RESULT
-------------------------------------
 1   (0)SP_CENSUS0      (0)SR_CENSUS0
 2         1                   4
 3         2            (0)SR_CENSUS0
 4         3                   1
 5   (0)SP_CENSUS0             5
```

my results may have 0,1,2,3,4,5 and I want only the result 0 to be changed and these two tables are joined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of `TARGET` if SR and SP are 1:1 via `CODE` field?

You can use `table.field` in your `case` statements:

```
select case when SP.CENSUS = '0' then 'SP_CENSUS0'
    else SP.CENSUS
    end as SP_RESULT,

    case when SR.CENSUS = '0' then 'SR_CENSUS0'
    else SR.CENSUS 
    end as SR_RESULT
FROM SR JOIN SP ON SR.CODE = SP.CODE
```

Also: watch out for data types, if Census column is number, you will have to `CAST` to `VARCHAR` in the `ELSE` assignment.

Comment: I was gonna use some other column from TARGET table. (which i didnot write down in here:( )